# Automatically update a data frame in Shiny from Scraping JIRA REST API

Tags: r, shiny, jira, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am attempting to automatically update a data frame in a Shiny Application that scrapes JIRA's rest API to populate visuals.

I am borrowing from what I found [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863987/make-a-query-and-data-frame-reactive-and-refresh-it-on-every-5-minutes) but the DB vs. Web Scrape doesn't seem to have a universal solution.

I am trying to globally define **defects** data (and update globally every 6 minutes) but when I attempt to filter the global data frame I get the *Error in eval: object 'defects' not found* error.
**Here is the Global Function I use to gather Updates**

```
Getupdates <- function(qfrequency){



 if(!exists("nextCall")){
    lastcall <<- Sys.time()
    message("Initiating")



 baseURL <<- "https://oneit.wba.com/jira/rest/api/2/search?fields=created,resolutiondate,customfield_13601,customfield_11014,creator,assignee,reporter,customfield_13400,customfield_11014,customfield_12501,key,status&jql=project%20in%20(RXQE)%20AND%20issuetype%20=%20Bug%20AND%20%22Business%20Priority%22%20!=%20EMPTY%20AND%20status%20!=%20Removed&maxResults=500"
    maxResults = 500
    resultIndex <<- -1;
    totalRecords <<- 0
    pages <- list()
    i<<-1
    while(resultIndex < totalRecords){
      url <<- paste0(baseURL, "&startAt=",resultIndex,"&maxResults=",maxResults) #CaPs MaTtER!
      rawExport <<- fromJSON(url, flatten=TRUE)

      resultIndex <<- rawExport$startAt + nrow(rawExport$issues)

      totalRecords <<- rawExport$total
      pages[[i]] <<- rawExport$issues
      i<<-i+1

    }
    defects <- rbind_pages(pages)
    nextCall <<- Sys.time() + qfrequency
    message("Got Initial Data")
  }
  else if (Sys.time() >= nextCall){
    lastcall <<- Sys.time()
    message(paste0(Sys.time(), " Querying Periodically"))

    baseURL <<- "https://oneit.wba.com/jira/rest/api/2/search?fields=created,resolutiondate,customfield_13601,customfield_11014,creator,assignee,reporter,customfield_13400,customfield_11014,customfield_12501,key,status&jql=project%20in%20(RXQE)%20AND%20issuetype%20=%20Bug%20AND%20%22Business%20Priority%22%20!=%20EMPTY%20AND%20status%20!=%20Removed&maxResults=500"
    maxResults = 500
    resultIndex <<- -1;
    totalRecords <<- 0
    pages <- list()
    i<<-1
    while(resultIndex < totalRecords){
      url <<- paste0(baseURL, "&startAt=",resultIndex,"&maxResults=",maxResults) #CaPs MaTtER!
      rawExport <<- fromJSON(url, flatten=TRUE)

      resultIndex <<- rawExport$startAt + nrow(rawExport$issues)

      totalRecords <<- rawExport$total
      pages[[i]] <<- rawExport$issues
      i<<-i+1

    }
    defects <- rbind_pages(pages)
    nextCall <<- Sys.time() + qfrequency
    message("Got Updated Data")

  }
  else{
    return()
  }
}
```

**And the Beginning of the server code where I believe the error is origniating**

```
 server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    autoInvalidate()
    # 300 seconds is 5 minute updates
    Getupdates(UpdateR8)
  })

  Quality <- reactive({

    rawNames <- c("fields.created", "fields.resolutiondate", "fields.customfield_13601.value", 
                  "fields.creator.displayName", "fields.assignee.displayName",
                  "fields.customfield_13400.value","fields.customfield_11014.value",
                  "fields.customfield_12501.value",
                  "key", "fields.status.name", "fields.reporter.displayName")


    myBugs <- defects %>% dplyr::select(rawNames) })
```

Any help on this would be wonderful!

Comment: Have you tried `defects <<- rbind_pages(pages)` ?

Comment: YOU ARE A HERO. This seems to be working swimmingly. Thank you so much! Saved my ears a bit of yelling.